# я не понимаю ка сделать так чтоб в discord.py сообщения пользователей заменялись эмбидами

Tags: python, discord.py

не понимаю это в документации тоже не понятно

пытался найти инфу на рзных сайтах

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какой вопрос, такой и ответ. Привожу пример рабочего embed, разобраться и сделать под себя не сложно.

```
import discord
from discord import Embed
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def embed(ctx):

    main_page = discord.Embed(title='НАЗВАНИЕ', colour=discord.Color.orange()) ## можно указать цвет

    main_page.set_author(
        name="Можно кликнуть и перейти",
        url="https://www.google.com/", ## можно оставить ссылку для перехода
        icon_url=bot.user.avatar.url) ## аватар

    main_page.add_field(name="Имя 1", value="Поле 1", inline=False) ## поле 1
    main_page.add_field(name="Имя 2", value="Поле 2", inline=False) ## поле 2 с переносом на новую строчку

    main_page.add_field(name="Имя 3", value="Поле 3", inline=True) ## поле 3
    main_page.add_field(name="Имя 4", value="Поле 4", inline=True) ## поле 4 без переноса, справа от поля 3
    
    embed = await ctx.send(embed=main_page)

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

При желании можно сделать даже листание страниц embed через реакции.

Comment: Если Вы имели ввиду что-то другое, то уточните вопрос. 
Пожалуйста, если данный ответ смог решить Вашу проблему, отметьте его галочкой, указав как решение.